# Contradictory rules in robots.txt

Tags: web-scraping, robots.txt

I'm attempting to scrape a website and these two rules seem to be contradictory in robots.txt

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: *
Allow: /
```

Does `Allow: /` mean that I can scrape the entire website, or just the root? As if means I can scrape the entire site then this is directly contradictory to the previous rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are following the [original robots.txt standard](https://www.robotstxt.org/orig.html):

- The `*` in the disallow line would be treated as a literal rather than a wildcard.  That line would disallow URL paths that start with an asterisk.  All URL paths start with a `/`, so that rule disallows nothing.
- The `Allow` Rule isn't in the specification, so that line would be ignored.
- Anything that isn't specifically disallowed is allowed to be crawled.

**Verdict**: You can crawl the site.

---

Google and a few other crawlers support wildcards and allows. If you are following Google's extensions to robots.txt, here is [how Google would interpret this robots.txt](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/robots/robots_txt):

- Both `Allow: /` and `Disallow: *` match any specific path on the site.
- In the case of such a conflict, the more specific rule (ie longer) rule wins.  `/` and `*` are each one character, so neither is considered more specific than the other.
- In a case of a tie for specificity, the least restrictive rule wins. `Allow` is considered less restrictive than `Disallow`.

**Verdict**: You can crawl the site.